# Calculate values for previous 3 weeks dynamically for each week in a year

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a way to find the qty_sold of each item for **previous 3 weeks** for every week in a year and categorize as "high", if more than 20 items sold in **any of the 2 previous weeks**

open to both sql and python. Any help is appreciated.

For example, in the data below, the qty_sold for apple, say for week 51, the qty_sold > 20 for any of 2 weeks in the previous 3 weeks i.e. 50th, 49th and 48th weeks, which is 143, 111 and 18 respectively, it's categorized as high.

[image]

My final output looks like below:

[image]

*Highlighted rows have sufficient data in the example*

Thank you

Comment: Your description of the logic and the example don't seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> categorize as "high", if more than 20 items sold in any of the 2 previous weeks

I'm not sure if this is the exactly logic, but whatever you want to do, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when (lag(qty_sold, 1, 0) over (partition by item order by weeknum rows) > 20)::int +
                  (lag(qty_sold, 2, 0) over (partition by item order by weeknum rows) > 20)::int +
                  (lag(qty_sold, 3, 0) over (partition by item order by weeknum rows) > 20)::int >= 2                      
             then 'high' else 'low'
        end) as frequency
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is almost similar to what I'm looking for. however, in my case for few items few weeks are missing. They don't have all the 52 weeks. what should I do in that case?